# Can't modify style in custom theme using Grunt

Tags: css, magento2.1.6, less-css, grunt, styles

I have custom theme **Hiddentechies/bentriz**

[image]

**theme.js**

```
bentriz: {
    area: 'frontend',
    name: 'Hiddentechies/bentriz',
    locale: 'ja_JP',
    files: [
      'css/source/custom',
      'css/source/extends',
      'css/source/navigation',
      'css/source/theme'
    ],
    dsl: 'less'
}
```

I run the following command:

```
grunt exec:bentriz

grunt less:bentriz

grunt watch
```

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_mode.html

There's an error when I run the **grunt exec:** and **grunt less:**
[image]

[image]

and when I run grunt watch then modify the _custom.less,nothing happened so I can't see the changes in the theme. Where did I go wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code in **theme.js** file as below:

```
bentriz: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Hiddentechies/bentriz',
        locale: 'ja_JP',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
 },
```

And import custom less files in `_sources.less` file as path below:

```
app\design\frontend\Hiddentechies\bentriz\web\css\source
```

`@import '_custom.less';`

If `_sources.less` is not exist over above path then copy this file from parent theme or Blank theme and import your custom less files, You do not need to declare this file in **theme.js**.

Run following command

```
grunt exec:bentriz    
grunt less:bentriz    
grunt watch
```

Comment: Is it related to this when the changes is not reflected on **styles-l.css**? Because when I run `grunt less:bentriz` only **style-m.css** is created.

Comment: I am talking about Magento default behavior in above post.
Then i think there were theme customization, You can check in view source `styles-l.css` is not removed or may be any other customization.